# Does end of support of AngularJS mean applications will stop working in Chrome?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, end-of-life

I understand that AngularJS will stop being supported in July 2021; after that date, some changes to jQuery etc. might cause AngularJS applications to stop working and AngularJS will not be updated.

I have an AngularJS-based application running in an isolated environment with Internet connectivity normally turned off, i.e. the application doesn't require Internet connection since all AngularJS, jQuery and other JS libraries are embedded in the application. Internet is periodically turned on just to update the Chrome browser used to run the application.

Let's assume that after the end of support period for AngularJS I keep all AngularJS, jQuery and other JS libraries unchanged, but I do allow Chrome browser to periodically update itself.

Question: in such scenario, is there a risk that my application will stop working after updating Chrome, so I should consider freezing Chrome version as well? Or would updating only the browser not cause any changes to the application behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't impose certain client-side libraries or their versions on the users. If you don't upgrade any libraries in your app, you should be just fine with your current lib setup. Your app may become vulnerable if some new bugs are found in the outdated libraries, but apart from that, I wouldn't worry too much.

jQuery that you've explicitly pointed out shouldn't be a problem, if you stay within the minor versions and not upgrade to new major version. But even though, the new major versions may still have breaking changes non-related to the functionality you use within jQuery. Check changelogs of those specific new versions. But if your app isn't critical, you can just stay at the versions you're using now if they satisfy the requirements of your app.